# Fetch API cannot load in Electron

Tags: node.js, cross-domain, electron, fetch

I have an electron app set through the [React CLI](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c). It seems to work fine but when I try and do an external HTTP request though:

```
https.get('https://blockchain.info/q/24hrprice', (result) => {
    console.log('RATE: ', result);
});
```

I get:

```
Fetch API cannot load https://blockchain.info/q/24hrprice. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a cross-origin request (your requesting domain is different than the API's domain) and browsers have special rules around that. In a Node context (i.e. via node's `http`/`https` modules), you don't have to worry about CORS and can in general do lower level work on network requests. Browsers, on the other hand, have a lot of security around CORS. When you use `fetch` your network request is going through Chromium's networking layer and so it's subject to those restrictions. When you use node's http/https, you're using node's. It's sort of a confusing point about Electron--a renderer process seems like a normal web context but you actually have access to all of node.js' APIs too, allowing you to things you can't do in a plain browser.

I would check and see if including an API key in that request changes the response of the API (maybe that triggers their API adding the appropriate CORS headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin). Maybe the API wasn't meant to be called within a browser context and so a more node.js oriented approach is the way to go.

This is a great article on CORS and the ways to deal with it: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b

Comment: Thank you. What I do not understand however is why Electron cannot use Chromium's functions and make a call through the browser rather than through code that runs in the browser?

Comment: @MikeM electron can use internal socket functions, but they need to be exposed to the browser context through a native call - javascript bridge. Nightmarejs does something like this through actions, maybe you can check out their implementation.

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare ;-)